# Existence of a fixed-point free map in a manifold

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, fixed-point-theorems

I'm having some to proof a question. I have to show that a compact manifold that admits a nowhere vanishing smooth vector field has a smooth map fixed-point free homotopic to the identity map.

I know that there exists a one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms that are smoothly homotopic to the identity, in fact the global flow of this vector field plays this role, since θ:R×M→M is a smooth left-action.

My question is: How can I show that exists t0∈R such that θt0 has no fixed points? (Here θt0(x)=θ(t0,x).

Comment: This isn't an appropriate forum for homework-type questions.

Comment: It is not a homework, it is a little doubt of mine in my self-study.

Comment: You could try math.stackexchange.com, that would be more appropriate.

Comment: FYI, it's relatively easy to construct a flow associated to a fixed-point free vector field where your map $\theta(t_0, \cdot)$ has fixed points for all $t_0 \in \mathbb R$.  You might want to think about examples like that.  A once-punctured plane does the job.  You can write the vector field in polar coordinates.

Comment: Crossposted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104186/existence-of-a-fixed-point-free-map-in-a-manifold

Comment: I didn't check it, but I think the standard technique should do the job: if there were a fixed point for each $t$, those points would converge as $t\to0$, and something bad would happen at the limit point (the velocity vector would vanish?)

Comment: @Alex: if the manifold is non-compact that limit point might not be on the manifold.

Comment: @RyanBudney Yes, but in the OP's question it **is** compact. I'm not objecting your example, just giving a hint to OP.

Answer (score 1):

A more general version of this result is proved by Brown and Fadell in:

MR0184236 (32 #1709) Reviewed 
Brown, Robert F.; Fadell, Edward
Nonsingular path fields on compact topological manifolds. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 16 1965 1342–1349.